# storybook darkmode not playing nice

Tags: html, css, svelte, tailwind-css, storybook

So I am using storybook for my svelte + tailwind app, and I am now trying to make sure that I can toggle darkmode.

So for my `tailwind.config.js` I added this

```
module.exports = {
  darkMode: "class",
```

and I installed this addon to storybook
https://github.com/hipstersmoothie/storybook-dark-mode

with this config `.storybook/preview.js`

```
export const parameters = {
  darkMode: {
    darkClass: "dark",
    stylePreview: false,
  },
```

And by looking in the DOM of the storybook iframe I can see that "dark" is applied to the body.
But when I create a component with this HTML

```
<div class="inline">
  <div class="w-8 h-8 bg-blue-500 dark:bg-green-500" />
</div>
```

the box is always blue.
So I thought maybe purgecss was removing it, and so I added `safelist: ["dark"]` to it's options but without any luck.

So to make things more complicated I tested this component

```
<div class="inline">
  <div class="w-8 h-8 bg-blue-500 dark:bg-green-500" />
</div>
<div class="inline dark">
  <div class="w-8 h-8 bg-blue-500 dark:bg-green-500" />
</div>
```

and to my surprise, one of the boxes turned green.

Honestly, I am not entirely sure if this is because of svelte, storybook, tailwind, or the darkmode storybook plugin.

But I would really appreciate help if anyone has seen something similar

Answer (score 0):

You could try ignoring `purgecss` when watching for storybook.

I am not sure about your exact setup but in my case I added a conditional in `postcss.config.js` for storybook to work correctly:

```
const isProduction =
  !process.env.ROLLUP_WATCH &&
  !process.env.LIVERELOAD &&
  process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development'

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    require('tailwindcss'),
    ...(isProduction ? [purgecss] : [])
  ]
};
```

My `.storybook/preview.js` contains the following:

```
export const parameters = {
  darkMode: {
    stylePreview: true,
    darkClass: 'dark',
    lightClass: 'light',
  }
}
```

The only thing which still doesn't work after this is the white text in dark mode, so I had to add `.dark { color: white; }` to my css.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well but it was because I defined a prefix of `vc-` in my `tailwind.config.js` file.

When I configured the addon https://github.com/hipstersmoothie/storybook-dark-mode, I used the class `dark` not `vc-dark` in `.storybook/preview.js`:

```js
export const parameters = {
  darkMode: {
    dark: { ...themes.dark },
    light: { ...themes.light },
    darkClass: 'dark',
    stylePreview: true
  }
}
```

should be

```js
export const parameters = {
  darkMode: {
    dark: { ...themes.dark },
    light: { ...themes.light },
    darkClass: 'vc-dark',
    stylePreview: true
  }
}
```

Not sure if you, (OP), have a prefix defined in your `tailwind.config.js` file but it's something to watch out for, if others are having the same issue.

Even with the prefix, you can still use the `dark` variant normally, just don't forget to use the prefix when referencing class names after the variant:

```html
<div class="vc-bg-blue-500 dark:vc-bg-green-500" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because components are rendered inside of an iframe and storybook-dark-mode (SDM) only sets the class to "dark" on the body of the main document.

I verified this by inspecting and adding it manually. Assuming that you have `darkMode: 'class'` set in your tailwind config, you should see it work as soon as you set `<body class="dark">` inside that iframe. This is why when OP wrapped it in a parent with "dark", it worked for that instance only.

#### First attempt

The question to me is how to get that class applied to the body of the iframe as well? Reading SDM docs, it implies that it would apply it to the app as well as the preview window, but that doesn't seem to happen for me.

Interestingly, there is an add-on called storybook-tailwind-dark-mode (STDM) which adds "dark" to the `<html>` of the iframed document, so that's good; but it's a separate button. You can have your components render in dark or light mode independent of dark mode on the app itself.

This is currently the only way it's working for me and I'd like to see/make a fork off one of these where it does both at once.

FWIW, without Tailwind, we were using a ThemeProvider from StyledComponents that leveraged `useDarkMode()` from SDM to then pass that down to all the StyledComponents (which we're migrating away from in favor of Tailwind). It would be nice to leverage that somehow.

#### Final answer

That previous paragraph gave me some inspiration. Storybook has [decorators](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/writing-stories/decorators), which are basically functions that return components. We can wrap our stories with some HTML and give it a class based on `useDarkMode()`.

Below is more or less what I ended up using and it's working great. One button to control dark mode, no need for an additional tailwind-specific dependency, and I'm still able to use my StyledComponent theming for the components that haven't been migrated yet.

`.storybook/theme.js`

```
import React from 'react'
import { ThemeProvider } from 'styled-components'
import { themeV2, GlobalStylesV2 } from 'propritary-design-library'
import { useDarkMode } from 'storybook-dark-mode'
import '../src/index.css'

const ThemeDecorator = storyFn => {
  const mode = useDarkMode() ? 'dark' : 'light'

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={themeV2(mode)}>
      <section className={mode}>
        <GlobalStylesV2 />
        {storyFn()}
      </section>
    </ThemeProvider>
  )
}

export default ThemeDecorator
```

`.storybook/preview.js`

```
import { addDecorator } from '@storybook/react'
import ThemeDecorator from './theme'

addDecorator(ThemeDecorator)

export const parameters = {
  controls: {
    matchers: {
      color: /(background|color)$/i,
      date: /Date$/,
    },
  },
}
```